# Converting unix string to date inside template ngIf

Tags: angular

Is there a way where I can parse a unix string into a date inside a ngIf?

I was guessing you would use a pipe, but when I try that, it doesn't evaluate the discription correctly. The element is visible no matter with this

```
*ngIf="now < auction.auctionEndDateTime | date:'yMMdd'
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the default [`DatePipe`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts) pipe to include your condition "now < some time" (i.e. check if date is in the future). Try the following

**date-valid.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateValid'
})
export class DateValidPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    super(locale);
  }

  transform(value: any, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): any {
    return (new Date().getTime() < value) ? super.transform(value, format, timezone, locale) : false;
  }
}
```

Now you could use it in the template in a `*ngIf` directive like you wish

```html
<div *ngIf="(auction.auctionEndDateTime | dateValid:'yMMdd') as validDate">
  {{ validDate }}
</div>
```

The `{{ validDate }}` interpolation will only be rendered if the date is in the future.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9shacn)

#### Update: Use [`ngx-simple-countdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-simple-countdown?activeTab=readme)

If your UNIX timestamp is in **seconds**, then you should multiply it by 1000 to convert it into **milliseconds**.

```html
<div *ngIf="(auction.auctionEndDateTime * 1000 | dateValid:'yMMdd') as validDate">
  <div
    class="countdown"
    simpleCountdown
    [dateTo]="auction.auctionEndDateTime"
    [language]="'fr'"
    [endMessage]="'custom end message'"   
    [reactive]="false"
    [styles]="'
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align:center;
      color: red;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px 4px;
      font-weight: bold;
    '"
  ></div> 
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h9fuqe)

In the example, the object `auction = { auctionEndDateTime: '1981242400' }` is only an example to reproduce your exact object structure. You don't have to declare the object exactly the same way I did. It's an ***example***. Replace it with your own object.

#### Update: Hide the timer when it's complete

I've adapted the countdown timer with two small changes. See my comment for the changes.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h9fuqe)

Comment: I added that like this ```*ngIf="(time | dateValid:'yMMdd') as auction.auctionEndDateTime"```, but I'm getting the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined```. Do you know why that is? I have the pipe imported in app.module.ts + declarations too.

Comment: @user6680: No, the variable after the `as` keyword holds the value from the `*ngIf`. You need to use it like I've shown here in the answer. It should be `*ngIf="(auction.auctionEndDateTime | dateValid:'yMMdd') as time"` - here the `time` could be anything you wish to use in the template. But `auction.auctionEndDateTime` is the UNIX timestamp from your component TS file.

Comment: I don't think this will work for me if I have to {{validDate}} because I'm using a countdown library and the way it works is you have to put the output in the tag like this ```<div
  class="countdown"
  simpleCountdown
  [dateTo]="1581242400"
  [language]="'fr'"
  [endMessage]="'custom end message'"
  [reactive]="false"
  [hideUnit]="'ds"
  [styles]="'
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
  '"
></div>```  Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-simple-countdown?activeTab=readme

Comment: @user6680: The `{{ validDate }}` is only an illustration to show you how to use the value. And seeing that your coundown module accepts UNIX timestamps as input. You could just say `<div [dateTo]="auction.auctionEndDateTime"...>`. The three dots here (`...`) is a placeholder for the remaining part of the `div` elements. **DON'T** use it directly. And even if you want to use the `validDate` in your countdown module you can say `<div [dateTo]="validDate"...>`. If you're new to Angular, please go their [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some of the basics.

Comment: @user6680: I've updated the answer to use your `ngx-simple-countdown` library. I've also included an additional working example.

Comment: I managed to get it to semi-work. I have one more question. So currently when the times runs to 0, it doesn't hide the ```.countdown``` class via ngIf until I refresh the page. So it evaluates the expression correctly, but it doesn't remove it right away. Do you know if I can do something to make it disappear right when it hits 0? I added another div above it to replace the original one. Here's my solution: https://pastebin.com/PLuJPeXq

Comment: I created a stackblitz to demonstrate: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vfefeu  Just replace all of the unix stamps with a timestamp 1 min the in future and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @user6680: That's because the condition is checked only once at the beginning and never checked again. So the end-message is shown. At the moment there is no way to know if the timer is complete from the library. But the directive itself is quite straight-forward. So I've adapted it with two small changes: 1. Upon completion it doesn't display the custom message, it doesn't display anything. 2. Include an `EventEmitter` to let us know that the timer is complete. We could then use it to disable the `countdown` class applied to the `div`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have to go somewhere for a couple hours, but I'll try it later today. My only concern with this solution is the ```timerComplete``` boolean. If there are multiple auctions and only one of them ended, wouldn't this solution only work with one auction? The boolean would be used on other auctions too I would think and affect the ones that haven't ended yet?

Comment: @user6680: Each will need a separate boolean. **Please try something on your own before questioning.** If you can't, google it. You could've just copy pasted multiple timers and see the effect for yourselves.